# C++ pointer trick

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I'm trying to understand how this C++ pointer trick really works. In MSDN [Obtaining a File Name From a File Handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) we can see:

```
// Copy the drive letter to the template string
*szDrive = *p;
```

At the first they declare an "template string" that will receive the drive letter without the trailing backslash (`TCHAR szDrive[3] = TEXT(" :");`) and then they do this pointer trick and voilà! I've tryied to disasembly but no clue at all:

```
            *szDrive = *p;
011D178D  mov         eax,dword ptr [p]  
011D1793  mov         cl,byte ptr [eax]  
011D1795  mov         byte ptr [ebp-214h],cl
```

I'm afraid that is the lamest trick ever...

Comment: Actually, it's not c++ but C

Comment: It's not so much of a trick as normal pointer usage.

Comment: @galinette is related to an MSDN C++ article. Thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since in C++ char-arrays and char-pointers are in many ways equivalent, they are dereferencing both pointers to copy one element from one array to the other.

You could equivalently express the same functionality like this, which might make it easier to understand what they are doing:

```
szDrive[0] = p[0];
```

Comment: @youngrp  Careful.. Technically there are copying the first `TCHAR`.  This may or may not be a byte, depending on the platform. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx

Comment: @PeterM sure. I'm not using TCHAR but good point. I never uses UNICODE but many people does ;)

Answer (score 8):

This code:

```
*szDrive = *p;
```

is equivalent to:

```
szDrive[0] = p[0];
```

which means you copy first symbol from string `p` to string `szDrive`, which is drive letter in this case.